# Live Chat fails after SSL Cert installation

Tags: ssl, proxy, apache2, odoo

After installing SSL Certification for Odoo so that we could get our HTTPS protocol up and running Live Chat fails.
All other Apps seem to work fine.

We added this to our Apache conf but it does not seem to work with Live Chat.

```
 # Comment to disable proxy
 ProxyRequests            Of
 ProxyPreserveHost     On 
 ProxyPass                   /longpolling/ http://localhost:8072/longpolling/ retry=0
 ProxyPassReverse      /longpolling/ http://localhost:8072/longpolling/ retry=0 
ProxyPass                   /                    http://localhost:8069/ retry=0 
ProxyPassReverse      / http://localhost:8069/ retry=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Chrome browser blocked the Live Chat "window" but it worked fine in Opera browser so that peace of proxy code works fine in Apache site config. It works even in ISPconfig's site/apache/options to redirect to previously installed Odoo website. Odoo keeps removing the S in httpS in Odoo Settings but that did not seem to matter.